# Why are bin and obj folders not getting created when I am building a csproj file on azure devops using pipeline?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am building a C# dot net project on Azure dev ops using pipelines. The build runs successfully, but after the build, I need to see the bin and obj folders for the project in the artifacts, from where I need to pick up the compiled dlls, but bin and obj folders are not getting created. Below is the build command in the pipeline yaml code:

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
   solution: 'C#\Ignify.eComIntegration\EventLogger\EventLogger.csproj'
   msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package 
   /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true 
   /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
   platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
   configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

Also, given below is a part of the code from the csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
<DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
<Optimize>true</Optimize>
<OutputPath>d:\a\1\s\C#\Ignify.eComIntegration\EventLogger\bin\Release\</OutputPath>
<DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
<ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
<WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
```

Please suggest what can be done to get the folders created.

Answer (score 0):

Your build task just create a package to deploy in `$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)` folder. You need to add additional build step to copy additional files: [Copy Files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). Something like this:

`- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  inputs:
    Contents: |
     **\bin\**
     **\obj\**
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'`

Comment: Will it work even if the bin and obj folders have not been created in the artifact ?

Comment: @TVicky, here is the sequence of tasks that work for me: Build solution, Publish symbols path, Copy Files task, Publish Artifact.

Comment: @TVicky I have updated answer and tested this task. Use `**\bin\**` and `**\obj\**` as contents template.

Comment: @ShamraiAleksander, The bin and obj folders are getting created for the other solutions, but not for the one that I want.